# zend file not included

Tags: php, zend-framework

im following some example for doing [login in Zend](http://akrabat.com/zend-auth-tutorial/)

using Zend_Form

but i get an error when trying to load a view

> Fatal error: Class 'Application_Form_Login' not found in
>   /Users/manuel/projects/zend_template/zend_template/application/controllers/AuthController.php
>   on line 13

this is the code on that file on that line

```
public function indexAction()

        {

      [line 13] $form = new Application_Form_Login();
 ...}
```

i Have a form on

> application\forms\Login.php

created on CLI

and this one have the form code

```
class Application_Form_Login extends Zend_Form
{

    public function init()
    { ...
```

So, i have my Application_Form_Login
but what is the problem?

thanks

Comment: Did you wrote any thing in bootstrap..?

Comment: @TomPHP hi thanks, no nothing, is empty class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap{} .. what shall i have? tnx

Comment: make sure the folder that contains the Application directory is in include_path and your application.ini should have a entry in it for AutoloaderNamespaces.Application = Application_

Comment: I think this link will be usefull http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html

Comment: Did you `require` `application\forms\Login.php` on top? did you try `Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();` before assigning `$form`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try checking your application.ini file to see if it has the 'Application' namespace registered. If your models/forms etc begin with Application_ you have to configure the autoloader to find them.

In application.ini add:

appnamespace = "Application"

Or in your bootstrap class add this:

protected $_appNamespace = 'Application';